# Unresolved compilation problem: String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please help me with this issue:

> Unresolved compilation problem: String literal is not properly closed
>   by a double-quote

```
package intruduction;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("WebDriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\ramum\\Downloads\\softwares\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("http:\\google.com\");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change keyword `WebDriver` to **webdriver** within **`WebDriver.chrome.driver`**

i.e. change the line:

```
System.setProperty("WebDriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\ramum\\Downloads\\softwares\\chromedriver.exe");
```

To

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\ramum\\Downloads\\softwares\\chromedriver.exe");
```